# Tableview Height Adjustments for IOS11 with out Autolayout

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, ios11

I was using UiTableview in UiScrollview and i don't use autolayout feature. My tableview was cutting/hiding data/rows at the end. I've found can adjust height dynamically from ios 11

I've tried it for it

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0; // set to whatever your "average" cell height is
```

Note: All the tables in my app misbehaves like this

But it doesn't help me.Can any one suggest me how to fix it
.Tnx in Advance

Comment: Can you attach screenshots and post more codes please?

Answer (score 0):

If you use UITableViewAutomaticDimension , and maybe your cells must use AutoLayout.